# Getting Global Total Number of Tweets Within 5 Minute Block Using Tweet ID

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, tweets, twitterapi-python

I have a dataset with all tweets from a certain hashtag over 2 days. I can get the number of tweets in my dataset over any 5 minute period using date, but I would like to also get the number of total tweets on Twitter's platform within that same 5 minute time period. I have the ID for each of my tweets, and Twitter API docs say "The full ID is composed of a timestamp, a worker number, and a **sequence number**". Considering there is a sequence number somewhere in the ID, I'm wondering if anyone knows how to find the total global number of tweets between two IDs. This will allow me to see how the frequency of tweets in my dataset over 5 minutes compare to the frequency of all tweets in Twitter's dataset over the same 5 minutes.